# Difference between window.location.href and top.location.href

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Can Anyone tell me the difference between `window.location.href` and `top.location.href` ?

And also where to use which one.

And which one will be better when redirecting after an ajax call in mvc?

Comment: i forgot to mention that i had to redirect to a new url in .net MVC .. when i used top.location.href it worked whereas window.location didn't.. can u also tell the reason why ????

Answer (score 140, accepted):

`window.location.href` returns the location of the current page.

`top.location.href` (which is an alias of `window.top.location.href`) returns the location of the topmost window in the window hierarchy.  If a window has no parent, `top` is a reference to itself (in other words, `window` === `window.top`).

`top` is useful both when you're dealing with frames and when dealing with windows which have been opened by other pages.  For example, if you have a page called `test.html` with the following script:

```
var newWin=window.open('about:blank','test','width=100,height=100');
newWin.document.write('<script>alert(top.location.href);</script>');
```

The resulting alert will have the full path to test.html – **not** about:blank, which is what `window.location.href` would return.

To answer your question about redirecting, go with `window.location.assign(url);`

Comment: Is it accurate to call `top.location.href` an *alias* of `window.top.location.href`?  I thought that a so called "global" variable is really a *shorthand for a property* of `window` whereas *alias* implies it is an independent variable which points to the same place.

Answer (score 30):

[`top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.top) object makes more sense inside frames. Inside a frame, `window` refers to current frame's window while `top` refers to the outermost window that contains the frame(s). So:

`window.location.href = 'somepage.html';` means loading `somepage.html` inside the frame.

`top.location.href = 'somepage.html';` means loading `somepage.html` in the main browser window.

Two other interesting objects are [`self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.self) and [`parent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.parent).

Answer (score 11):

The first one adds an item to your history in that you can (or should be able to) click "Back" and go back to the current page.

The second replaces the current history item so you can't go back to it.

See `window.location`:

- `assign(url)`: Load the document at the provided URL.
- `replace(url)`: Replace the current document with the one at the provided URL. The difference from the `assign()` method is that after using `replace()` the current page will not be saved in session history, meaning the user won't be able to use the Back button to navigate to it.

```
window.location.href = url;
```

is favoured over:

```
window.location = url;
```

Comment: For CORS issue its not working... how to solve this ?

Answer (score 9):

`top` refers to the window object which contains all the current frames ( father of the rest of the windows ). `window` is the current `window`.

http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserinspecific

so `top.location.href` can contain the "master" page link containing all the frames, while `window.location.href` just contains the "current" page link.