# canvas page out of facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have application of Url : apps.facebook.com/leaglecases/  which is redirecting my canvas page to my server as i click pagination in "featured court decisions tile" page.

Process to carry on:

```
Step1: go to my application url: apps.facebook.com/leaglecases/
Step2: click on Tile "Featured court decisions" tile the page displays.
step3: click on pagination of the page 1,2,3....and so on
   This page redirects to my server which is out of facebook.
```

Why i am facing this issue where i made the mistake pls guide me....:(
   The other tiles r working fine in this issue. I am using Javascript SDK here

Answer (score 0):

Your app server isn't responding. Anyway this can happen if you set `window.top.location.href` to the new location instead of `window.location.href`. `window.top` refers to the page which is parent of `iframe` (your app canvas).

More info at [Difference between window.location.href and top.location.href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332756/difference-between-window-location-href-and-top-location-href).

Comment: As i tried as per ur suggestion but i dint get solved my issue . can u get me where exactly i need to place this ??? i am using javascript SDK for this.

Comment: Well I have already explained that. I can try debugging it myself but it seems that your server never completes the response. My browser waits for forever and nothing shows up.