# get first parent of iframe javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a iframe inside test.aspx,when the user click on a pay button inside the Iframe,the iframe  redirct to check.aspx that has same iframe

if payment  was success on first time, `then window.parent.location.href==test.aspx`

if payment was failed the iframe redirect again to check.aspx,so now the

```
window.parent.location.href==check.aspx
```

while the payement was failed the the iframe keep redirect to check.aspx and the parent location keep changing ,so for example if the client failed 3 time,inside check.aspx I need to do `window.parent.parent.parent.location.href` to get test.aspx redirect.

when the user payment was success ,then I want to redirect the test.aspx but I can't know
how much child iframe window he has!

I need something like

window.parent[0].location.href=success.aspx,so I will be able to redirect the first father window.

Thanks for any Help

Baaroz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always get to the top window in JavaScript by using

```
window.top.location.href
```

For more info see: [Difference between window.location.href and top.location.href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332756/difference-between-window-location-href-and-top-location-href)

Comment: It's not and alias of `window.top...` It's just in the global scope. See: http://jsbin.com/uminen/2/edit

Comment: that simple,I cant believe I spent 3 hours searching the internet:)

Comment: @baaroz its always the simple things that catch me out

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
window.top.location.href
```

or:

```
var par = window.parent;
while ( par.parent ) {
    par = par.parent;
}

//par === window.top
```