# Extjs Ajax file download request C# MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, extjs, get, download

I want client to download a file stored on my db when clicked a button.
I send this ajax request and take it from the server side.

EXTJS:

```
downloadFile: function (a, b, c) {
    var feed_id =this.getMyfeedwindow().down('form').getComponent('FeedId').text;
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: '/Feed/Download',
        method: 'GET',
        params: {
            fileID: feed_id, //this.form.getComponent('file').value,
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert('failed  !');
        },
        success: function (response) {
            alert('success!');
        },
    });
},
```

then meet request with this code block.

C#:

```
 public void Download(string fileID){
    Response.ContentType = "application/force-download";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; Filename=\"Logo1.jpg\"");
    Response.BinaryWrite(data);
    Response.End();
 }
```

When I checked network with firebug, it seems my request returns successfully with these parameters.

```
Cache-Control   private
Content-Disposition attachment; filename="Logo1.jpg"
Content-Type    application/force-download
Date    Wed, 09 Jan 2013 12:51:54 GMT
Server  Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
X-AspNet-Version    4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version 4.0
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles   =?UTF-8?B?RTpcVXRrdUNhblxQcm9qZWN0c1xURlNcQlRPTVxCVE9NXEZlZWRcRG93bmxvYWQ=?=
```

Although it returns successful, download does not start. I read lots of questions and articles but most answers say adding force-download header solves the problem. Which point do I miss? Thanks.

Comment: What are you actually asking here? It's not clear.

Comment: Download does not start at the server side? I could not make it start. Response field in Firebug seems that filled with some data but there is no download.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To handle a Download you should use one of the provided helper

- System.Web.MVC.FilePathResult
- System.Web.MVC.FileStreamResult
- System.Web.MVC.FileContentResult

Most times I am using the `System.Web.MVC.FileStreamResult` mayself. Use it like

```
FileStreamResult result = new FileStreamResult(stream, contentType);
result.FileDownloadName = filename; // name of the downloaded file
```

**Update** *Just some Infos based on your edit*

You cannot start download using XHR request. But there are at least two ways how you can do it:

- If the file-path is fix and you know it set `top.location.href = "YourPath";` within the success handler of the ajax call. [Infos about **[top.location.href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332756/difference-between-window-location-href-and-top-location-href)**]
- If you create the file on the fly and want to return it you should create a hidden iframe and inject a form into it that then execute the request.

Comment: +1. I use `return File(photo, "image/jpg");` where photo is a byte[] from the database.

Comment: @tkcn I added some additional Infos about Filedownloads concerning AJAX calls to my post. They might interest you.

Comment: thanks, I have already used location.href. but it is good to learn iframe option. thanks. btw if you downvoted, shame on you. but if you didnot, shame on me :D

Answer (score 1):

After some search, I found that `location.href` does the same thing and opens a download dialog box. Same headers should be added to the response coming from the server. However, I still don't know why the other approach does not work.

```
var feed_id = this.getMyfeedwindow().down('form').getComponent('FeedId').text;
location.href = '/Feed/Download?fileID=' + feed_id;
```

this solved my problem.

Comment: it is possible to pass parameters like this.