# How to download file using JavaScript/ExtJs?

Tags: java, javascript, extjs

In jsp i get file from BD and want to download it on client:

```
<%
String num = request.getParameter("param");
Statement sta = null;
sta = conn.createStatement();
String fileName="";
String sql=("SELECT files,filename FROM filestock WHERE num =(SELECT filestock_id FROM parcels_temp WHERE num="+num+")");
ResultSet rs=sta.executeQuery(sql);
while(rs.next()){
    byte[] file = rs.getBytes("files");
    fileName=rs.getString("filename");
}
FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName));
BufferedOutputStream bs = new BufferedOutputStream(fs);
bs.write(file);
bs.close();
fs.close();
rs.close();
ps.close();
%>
```

I will PDF file. So i have some questions:
1. What i gonna do with file to send it to JavaScript.
2. Can i save this file using ExtJs 3.4 or JavaScript?

**UPDATE**

Now i try to send file from server to client:

```
<%
String num = request.getParameter("param");
Statement sta = null;
sta = conn.createStatement();
String fileName="";
byte[] file=null;
int bufferSize = 8192;
String sql=("SELECT files,filename FROM filestock WHERE num =(SELECT filestock_id FROM parcels_temp WHERE num="+num+")");
ResultSet rs=sta.executeQuery(sql);
while(rs.next()){
    file = rs.getBytes("files");
    fileName=rs.getString("filename");
}
File dFile=new File(fileName);
InputStream in1 = request.getInputStream();
int read;
while ((read = in1.read(file, 0, bufferSize)) != -1) {
    out.write(file, 0, read);
}
sta.close();
rs.close();
conn.close();
%>
```

But get error:

```
The method write(char[], int, int) in the type Writer is not applicable for the arguments (byte[], int, int)
```

So how to do it?

**UPDATE2**

Using this code i dont get any errors but in firebug i see that server nothing send to client:

```
<%
String num = request.getParameter("param");
Statement sta = null;
sta = conn.createStatement();
String fileName="";
byte[] file=null;
int bufferSize = 8192;
String sql=("SELECT files,filename FROM filestock WHERE num =(SELECT filestock_id FROM parcels_temp WHERE num="+num+")");
ResultSet rs=sta.executeQuery(sql);
while(rs.next()){
    file = rs.getBytes("files");
    fileName=rs.getString("filename");
}
//File dFile=new File(fileName);
FileOutputStream fout = fout = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
//BufferedInputStream in1 = new BufferedInputStream(fout);
InputStream in1 = request.getInputStream();
int read;
while ((read = in1.read(file, 0, bufferSize)) != -1) {
    fout.write(file, 0, read);
}
sta.close();
rs.close();
conn.close();
%>
```

Comment: Have you searched for it in SO ? You are not the first who is asking this...

Comment: @sra: Yeah im google it. But cant send file from server to cliet yet. Please watch to Update question. And it will nice if you says where im wrong.

Comment: I assume the client makes a request in which he requests a file? In that case you just handling a download. You now simply stream the content back to the user with a appropriate Header and mimetype. Here is a answer concerning ExtJS & C# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14235896/extjs-ajax-file-download-request-c-sharp-mvc/14236392#14236392 or

Answer (score 0):

You have simply to create a Download URL with a `Content-Disposition` Header.

Now the bad/good news (It depends on the point of view). You can not store a file through JavaScript onto a users-filesystem (expect the new [File-API](http://www.html5rocks.com/de/tutorials/file/filesystem/)). But this will sandbox your filesystem. So you can't make the browser store that file onto a certain path.

Comment: Its bad new. I cant use html5. And i cant understand: you says that its imposible to download files using JS? But how i download files from sites?

Comment: You can create a link or a window.open(). But the user can cancel a download. You cannot specify the location, where the client stires the file.