# Ext.Ajax call gets CSV but my browser is not downloading it - probably something with headers

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a CSV at my server but when I do Ajax, it just shows in my "Network" in Google Chrome when I "Inspect element".

Code is here:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "text/csv",
                'Content-Disposition': 'attachment'
            },
            url: 'php/files/' + tabid + '.csv'
});
```

What do I need to add to get my browser download a file on my local machine? Thank you! :)

*Ext-JS 4,
CakePHP 2.2.5*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot start download using XHR request. But there are at least two ways how you can do it:

- If the file-path is fix an you know it set `top.location.href = "YourPath";` within the success handler of the ajax call. **[top.location.href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332756/difference-between-window-location-href-and-top-location-href)**
- If you create the file and want to return it you should create a hidden iframe and inject a form into it that then execute the request.

Comment: I know the location and the file so I'll try top.location.href. Thank you. :)

Comment: I've spent a whole day trying this with Ext.Ajax and I've just needed a 1 line, and it's not even from Ext-JS? xD I hate you, JavaScript, I hate you. xD

Thank you, sra. It works.