# Comparison of "location" object in javascript

Tags: javascript, window.location

I want to know how "location"(window.location) object is compared in javascript i.e. which values are taken into consideration while comparing two "location" objects.

Suppose i have top.location = "http://www.abc.com" and self.location = "http://www.abc.com". If i compare them as (top.location == self.location), it gives false. Whereas, if i compare them as (top.location.href == self.location.href), it will gives true.

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: closely related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332756/difference-between-window-location-href-and-top-location-href.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`top.location` and `self.location` are [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) objects. Objects in JavaScript can't be directly compared using `==` or `===`, which is why `top.location != self.location`.

Since `top.location.href` and `self.location.href` are conventional strings, they can be compared as usual using `==` or, better, `===`.

Comment: +1 I Objects can't be compared in JS.  Thanks for letting us to know.

Comment: Yeah. So, is it that objects in javascript cannot be compared? Since, frame busting code uses `top.location`!=`self.location` and it works correctly.

Comment: I doubt it, they must be doing something else, although `top.location!=self.location` always equals `true` meaning the frame will always "bust"

Comment: Isn't there any method to achieve `top.location==self.location`?

Comment: Objects CAN be compared using == (property by property) or === (by reference).

Comment: @user2546340 I think this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript

Comment: @Virus721 What do you mean by reference? I've _never_ been able to compare objects without property by property iteration in JS

Comment: @Bojangles You can check if two references point to the same object using ===. At least this is what i read somewhere on SO some time ago.

Comment: So? How does that help in this case?

Comment: @Virus721 Do you mean "address"? How do we get reference or property of a object?

Comment: @user2546340 Non scalar variables (i.e objects and arrays) are references.

Comment: How do you compare objects using property or reference? Can you give one example?

Comment: Also, the location.assign() function assigns the value of type "String". Can we assign it in such a way that the value has a type "object" instead of "String"?

Comment: @Virus I said objects can't be _directly_ compared using `==` as the OP was doing, and it doesn't help in this case to see whether two references to an object point to the same real object. What have I said that's incorrect? So far, you appear to be the one who is incorrect in implying that objects can be directly compared with `==`

Comment: @Bojangles No you said they can't be compared using == or ===, which is a big difference.