# How to open an https website on a button click javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The piece of code I am using is

```
window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/";
```

But i stays on the same page,doesn't go to [google.com](http://www.google.com).I was able to get this work with an http page.

```
window.location.href = "http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_insert_document.htm";
```

This is the complete code for the same

```
<form name="form1" onsubmit="submis()" action="/post.php" method="POST"
```

and the function submis()

```
function submis()
{
     window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/";    
}
```

and post.php

```
if (!empty($_POST))
{
//saving the contents of the post request to a file.
}
```

Comment: I dont think so, maybe the error is somewhere else. see your console for errors.

Comment: Seems to work for me.. Check you `console` for any `error`..

Comment: Actually i have implemented this as a function which is called on onsubmit of a form and action for the same is another `php` page.Can this be an issue?

Comment: Unless you show us **complete problem description [code]**, we won't be able to tell, what's happening..

Comment: For me it did not work for both of your approaches.. you have `action` in `form` which is actually calling some `php` file and you have redirect code where you want to go to some `url`.. This combination would not work IMHO and usually this will navigate to the action mentioned `url`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao But this is working if I am specifying an `http` address.Cannot figure out why

Comment: @joseph Can you try adding **return false;** to the end of your submis() function

And then wherever you are calling the function, make sure you put return there, like **onsubmit="return submis()"**

Comment: @GuruprasadRao   I stumbled upon the solution (please see my answer) while looking for something else.If somebody can help me with the explanation for why this one works and not the one I have used in the code,would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make this work by changing the code to,

```
window.top.location.href="https://www.google.com"
```

Comment: I stumbled upon this solution while looking for something else.If somebody can help me with the explanation for why this one works and not the one I have used in the code,would be great@Gur

Comment: I hope **[this post here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332756/difference-between-window-location-href-and-top-location-href)** might help you understand what is actually happening..

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
        function goto(){
            window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/";
        }
    </script>
```

in html code `<a href="#" onclick="goto()">go to google</a>`

it works