# Open JavaScipt URL in new window

Tags: javascript

Wondering if anyone can help. I've created some code that depending on what option the user picks, they get taken to a specific URL. I have it all working fine, however, the URL won't open in a new window.

Any help would be brilliant.

This is the code:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var selectVal1 = $("#selectBox1").val();
    var selectVal2 = $("#selectBox2").val();
    $("#selectBox1").change(function() {
            selectVal1 = $("#selectBox1 option:selected").val();
    });
    $("#selectBox2").change(function() {
            selectVal2 = $("#selectBox2 option:selected").val();
    });
    
    $("#click").click(function() {
    
    if(selectVal1 == 'A' && selectVal2 == 'A'){
        location = "https://www.google.com/animalmanagement-25thaug", '_blank';}
    else if(selectVal1 == 'A' && selectVal2 == 'B'){        
        location = "https://www.google.com/animalmanagement-26thaug", '_blank';}
    if(selectVal1 == 'B' && selectVal2 == 'A'){
        location = "https://www.google.com/artdesign-25thaug", '_blank';}
    else if(selectVal1 == 'B' && selectVal2 == 'B'){        
        location = "https://www.google.com/artdesign-26thaug", '_blank';}
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.sthelens.ac.uk/book-slot/book-enrolment.js"></script>

<h3>Book Your Enrolment Slot</h3>
<select id="selectBox1">
  <option value="">Select which subject you would like to study?</option>
  <option value="A">Animal Management</option>
  <option value="B">Art &amp; Design</option>
</select>
<select id="selectBox2">
  <option value="">Select what date you would like to come in and enrol</option>
  <option value="A">Tuesday 25th August 2020</option>
  <option value="B">Wednesday 26th August 2020</option>
</select>
<input id="click" type="button" value="Book Now" class="button">
```

Comment: You're not setting the right JS variable to open a new URL.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332756/difference-between-window-location-href-and-top-location-href

Comment: Welcome to SO. It seems you've assumed how `location.href` works. You're using syntax like you would if it were a function, passing arguments to it. It's not; it's a live property, which expects a simple assignment - the URL. You can't pass a target window to it as a second param.

Answer (score 2):

[window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) might help

```
window.open(<url>);
```

Or

```
window.open(<url>, "_blank"); // opens in new tab
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use `window.open(your url)`** ..

Or you can refer this doc.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Answer (score 1):

You can use code below

```
$("#click").click(function() {
    
   if(selectVal1 == 'A' && selectVal2 == 'A'){
       var  location = "https://www.google.com/animalmanagement-25thaug";
   } else if (selectVal1 == 'A' && selectVal2 == 'B'){        
       var location = "https://www.google.com/animalmanagement-26thaug";
   } else if (selectVal1 == 'B' && selectVal2 == 'A'){
       var location = "https://www.google.com/artdesign-25thaug";
   } else if (selectVal1 == 'B' && selectVal2 == 'B'){        
       var location = "https://www.google.com/artdesign-26thaug";
   }
   var wind = window.open(location, '_blank');
   //wind.focus(); // If required

});
```